# AngularJS how to unit test to ensure directives like ng-click point to valid code

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine to write unit tests for our controllers, but wanted to get community feedback on how to handle this situation...

I have a controller - InvoiceController, like this:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('myController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.doSomething = function() {
            $scope.something = 'bar';
        };
    }
]});
```

In my unit tests I verify that my controller has the expected methods:

```
it('should be able to do some work', function() {

    // initialize scope properties
    scope.someProperty = 'foo';

    // load controller using those properties
    injectController();

    // do I have all of the functions necessary to do this work?
    expect(typeof (scope.doSomething)).toBe('function');

    // now execute test
    scope.doSomething();
    expect(scope.something).toBe('bar');       

}
```

And finally, in my html I have an element with an ng-click, like this:

```
<button ng-click="doSomehing()">Do Something</button>
```

Looks good, right?  BUT, did anyone catch what I did wrong?

My ng-click method is misspelled, but all tests are green and life seems rosy...until I try to click on that guy and nothing happens.  No render time error, no error on click.  Hmm.

Several times now as I'm refactoring code this has got me.  I rename doSomething to doSomethingCooler in the unit test and in the controller but miss a place in the html. After a minute of head scratching I see what was missed.

I'd love a way to ensure that the markup is valid.  E2E tests seem to be the obvious solution, but those are prone to fragility so we are hoping there are some alternatives.

If this were ASP.Net I would attach the click events from code behind so that I would get compile time errors vs run time errors.

Thoughts??

Thad

Comment: Why do you say prone to fragility? The test should load the DOM template, click the button, and then check that the result happened as expected, if not, the test fails, and you catch the places where you changed names or misspelled.

Comment: @aet - Good question.  It is my thought that when you have a system that is under active development having E2E tests leave you spending more time maintaining tests than actually coding for business needs. Once the system has final signoff and becomes stable, you can add more encompassing tests; until then I prefer to focus on testing with small, independent units of work that can be very quickly modified when necessary.  I accomplished this in ASP.Net by binding events at the server side rather than in the markup to ensure discrepancies are caught at compile time, not run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is get the template text and run `$compile` on it. And then link it to your controller's scope. Then you could do something like `dom.find('[ng-click]').click();`, which should throw if any of them is not defined in your controller's scope. This is similar to how you generally test directives.